# Why does Eclipse export my entire project as runnable JAR file?

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I have a Java project called Project1, containing some ten packages. In **package3**, I have a class called `MyPrgm` which I want to export as a runnable jar. This is fine and I can execute it in the command prompt / using a batch file.
 However, when I open `MyPrgrm.jar` archive using WinRAR I realize that every single class in Project1 is in the archive; is there a way to export only the classes that are required for the program to run? I am using Eclipse IDE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It does this because you told it to. If you only want to export one package, then only export one package. For instance, if you right click on the project and press Export, Eclipse will try to export everything in the project, but you can fine tune this easily via the export wizard. If you right click on a package and click Export, then Eclipse will try to export only that package.

In particular look at the "Jar File Specification" portion of the Export wizard where you can pick and choose what to export.

Comment: Thanks for replying. Where did I tell it to export the entire project, though? I right click package3 > Export > Runnable Jar File and select the launch configuration, but still the problem remains.

Comment: Don't do "Runnable Jar File" but rather Jar file. You can still make it runnable with the right settings.

Comment: Success! Using the export "Jar File" instead of "Runnable Jar File" with the correct settings worked indeed.

Comment: As a side question, how is the source code encapsulated when a program is a runnable jar file? If a developer created software using java, can't somebody unzip the jar and decompile the .class files to get the source code?

Comment: @jesterII: Again, look carefully at the options that are available in the export wizard. You can select whether or not to include source code.

Comment: I see what you mean, however something must be exported; the option I choose is 'export generated class files and resources', which gives the user access to my class files. 'export java source files' is deselected...

Comment: @jester: Yes, you must export the class files. There are utilities available that can obfuscate the class files, but if someone is strongly motivated to decompile your code, then they will, but that's true for any program created with any language.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want all the classes in the JAR, then choose export only for that particular package, not for the entire project.

Even if the above doesn't work (no reason why it shouldn't), you can still remove the additional classes from the executable. JAR is basically a ZIP archive, you can open it with any archive manager and add/remove files as you wish.

Comment: Thank you, I got it to work by selecting export as Jar File not Runnable Jar File, which does not give you the option to select which packages/classes you want to export.